# htaccess to hide html extention and addThis plugin

Tags: html, .htaccess, addthis

I am using this htaccess code to hide .html extention on my website, but when doing so addThis share plugin is not working. You can find addThis here: https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing

Is there any workaround for this?

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index(\.html)?(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index(\.html)?$ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by the plugin is not working?

Comment: When adding this htaccess code, the Like facebook button for example, displays 0 shares although the page has been shared more than 1 times. I think it's because this code redirects you from the .html page and removes the extension, but it was the only working code I found on the web about hiding the .html extention.

Comment: Facebook shares count are based on the url. So if the url has changed then the count will be zero... What is the url we are talking about?

Comment: So that means that I should have included this code before any page share was done? Isn't there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to total share counts for different URLs:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/206634-can-i-total-share-counts-for-two-different-urls-short-and-full-for-the-same-content-

and it's not a problem with the redirect, but an issue with addthis code.

You should have used the redirection code from the beginning.